# Display and shuffle an array in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, arrays, dictionary, next.js, shuffle

I'd like to create a single "Card" component containing some content like title, subtitle, etc picked from a data.js file which contains an array with all these elements. What I want to achive is, it must changes on every refresh giving a different result from the array picked randomly.

For the moment, I could display the single Card element using .map and .slice, but as I said, I'd like to make it changes on every refresh.

Card.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { curses } from "@/utils/curses";

function Card({ id, curse, russo, trad }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex text-center items-center h-[300px] p-3 bg-card">
      <div className="h-[280px] border-2 border-black p-4">
        <h1 className="font-bold p-4 text-4xl">{curse}</h1>
        <p>Russian: {russo} </p>
        <p>Meaning: {trad} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

page.js:

```
"use client";

import Card from "./components/Card";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { curses } from "@/utils/curses";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadCurse = curses;
    setData(loadCurse);
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div>
        {data.slice(0, 1).map((item, id) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={id}
              curse={item.curse}
              russo={item.russo}
              trad={item.trad}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

data.js:

```
export const curses = [
  {
    id: "1",
    curse: "Curse 1",
    russo: "",
    trad: "",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    curse: "Curse 2",
    russo: "XYZ",
    trad: "",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    curse: "Curse 3",
    russo: "AAA",
    trad: "",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    curse: "Curse 4",
    russo: "",
    trad: "",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    curse: "Curse 6",
    russo: "",
    trad: "",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    curse: "Curse 7",
    russo: "",
    trad: "",
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    curse: "Curse 8",
    russo: "",
    trad: "",
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    curse: "Curse 9",
    russo: "",
    trad: "",
  },
  {
    id: "9",
    curse: "Curse 10",
    russo: "",
    trad: "",
  },
];
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If I understood your question I think you are almost there. Instead of `slice` and `map`, I would go for using a Math.random() and just pulling out a single item from the array.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, actually I feel really close, but I don't know how to randomize the output. Since I'm also still learning React/Next.js, how can I edit my code in order to make it works with your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
import Card from "./components/Card";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { curses } from "@/utils/curses";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(curses[Math.floor(Math.random() * curses.length)]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div>
        {data && (
            <Card
              key={data.id}
              curse={data.curse}
              russo={data.russo}
              trad={data.trad}
            />
        )}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

**EDIT** keep in mind if you want to generate another card under any event without refreshing your browser page you can place the code in the effect into that event.

In case you want to add a button to make the content change:

```
import Card from "./components/Card";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { curses } from "@/utils/curses";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const generate = () => {
     setData(curses[Math.floor(Math.random() * curses.length)]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    generate();
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div>
        {data && (
            <Card
              key={data.id}
              curse={data.curse}
              russo={data.russo}
              trad={data.trad}
            />
        )}
    <button type="button" onClick={() => generate()}>Another</button>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, may I ask you one last thing: what if I'd like to add a button which makes the content change instead of refreshing the page?

Comment: Checkout the edition of the answer

Comment: As you can see the update is pretty simple and straightforward.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge and time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement this with `Math.random()` function of javascript

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { curses } from "@/utils/curses";

    const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
    
    export default function Home() {
      const [data, setData] = useState([]);
      const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const loadCurse = curses;
        const randomIndex = parseInt(loadCurse.length * Math.random());
        setData(loadCurse);
        setIndex(randomIndex)
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <main className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
          <div>
              {data.length > 0 && <Card
                  curse={data[index].curse}
                  russo={data[index].russo}
                  trad={data[index].trad}
                />}
          </div>
        </main>
      );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! For some reasons I get this error pasting your code: "ReferenceError: randomIndex is not defined"

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! It works like a charm, even if actually I had to remove " key={id}" in order to make it works because I got the error "ReferenceError: id is not defined
". Is it normal or is it wrong?

Comment: Yes you need to remove `key` prop